# Replace multiple addition sign (+) in a string with a single addition sign (+) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

In the following code, I am trying to replace multiple addition signs in a string with a single addition sign using Javascript. I am not getting the right regex expression for this please help!

Example: This++is+my+++++text --> This+is+my+text

**Code:**

```js
function doThis(){
document.getElementById("result").value = document.getElementById("TextInput").value.replace(/++/g,'+');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<textarea type="number" autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;">This++is+my+++++text</textarea><br><br>

<input class="button" type="button" value="Press" onclick="doThis()"><br/><br/>

Result: <input type="text" id="result">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about using [`/\+{2,}/gm`](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=m&re=%5C%2B%7B2%2C%7D)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `+`.

```js
function doThis() {
  document.getElementById("result").value =
    document.getElementById("TextInput").value.replace(/\++/g, '+');
}
```

```html
<textarea type="number" autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;">This++is+my+++++text</textarea><br><br>
<input class="button" type="button" value="Press" onclick="doThis()"><br/><br/> Result: <input type="text" id="result">
```